# Task tracker (more full-fledged and functional than Trello)

Tags: project-management

I’m in a situation where the number of tasks for current projects and the number of potential projects has increased to such an extent that it’s impossible to track everything with Trello.

I’m looking for a task tracker with the following requirements.

#### Requirements

- Number of users up to 20 people + 1 super user with extended rights
- Separation of roles (manager, admin etc.) with flexible rights
- The ability to share projects for specific users
- Customization of the interface for employees
- Email or SMS notifications
- Separation of tasks by status (e.g. task, test, completed, bug)
- Ticket assignment
- Option to choose a ticket from the number of unassigned
- Number of hours to implement the ticket
- The ability to set the cost per hour separately for each employee
- Statistics on users and projects
- Attachments for each ticket + discussions like in Trello
- Checklists for each ticket like in Trello

#### Optional

- Ability to indicate the cost of the project
- Time tracker out of the box / connection of an external time tracker
- Connection to git / github repositories with the commit for the ticket
- Chat with employees
- Notification system for employees
- Free or low-cost

#### Summary

Trello is not bad and part of my requirements can be implemented here, but maybe there’s something more full-fledged and functional. Cloud based preferably. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your one-time or monthly budget for non-fre apps? Are you already own a web server that can be used to install self-hosted software?

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend [**Redmine**](https://www.redmine.org/) as we use it successfully in our company.

[image: Redmine screenshot]

After reviewing your requirements I can confirm that Redmine supports all features either out of the box or via plugins. Basic task tracking, roles, ticket discussions and time tracking are already implemented into Redmine while expenses based on the tracked time are [available via plugins](https://www.redmine.org/boards/1/topics/6924).

It's a powerful software that is highly customizable. It is actively maintained and there are hundreds of plugins to add new features and several themes that look pretty awesome, for example the [Circle theme](https://www.redmineup.com/pages/themes/circle).

Redmine is basically free and open source software. If you already own a server you can install and try it. If you don't own a server, there are a lot of services like [Planio](https://plan.io/redmine-hosting/) that offer hosting for Redmine.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Deskun](https://deskun.com).

It's a cloud based solution integrated with Gmail (or G-Suite). It fits almost all of your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with an on-premise solution, [Eylean Board](http://www.eylean.com?utm_source=stack&utm_campaign=dovile) could be a nice fit.

Is an agile project management software equipped with project, task, team and time management as well as other common PM features. As far as your requirements go, it fits all of them out of the box, except the ability to set specific cost per hour for each employee, but maybe it is possible to find a workaround.

[image]